# 301 redirect for a WordPress site and subfolder to different domains

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 WordPress installation for example abc.com and abc.com/new/

Now I am planning to move the site to their own domain, i.e abc.com >> xyz.com and abc.com/new/ >> KLM.com.

So I was wondering how to accomplish this using .htaccess and where we should have this redirect .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside root .htaccess have this redirect rule as the first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://xyz-site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Then inside `/new/.htaccess` have this redirect rule as the first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://klm-site.com/$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Sorry anubhava I didn't check the answers in Stackoverflow. Just checking it now and letting you know

Comment: The First .htaccess files works fine and it redirect to newsite(xyz-site.com), as required, but the second htaccess file redirect to the site (klm-site.com) with a 404 error, seems like the second  htaccess is missing something.

Comment: say the old site is abc.com/new/ which should redirect to klm-site.com, it is giving 404 error after the redirecting to klm-site.com...

Comment: Thanks this works, but all the url now redirects to home page of the site i.e suppose if I give abc.com/new/wp-login.php or abc.com/new/wp-admin/ it is redirecting me back to http://klm-site.com